# Retry previous task action TPL

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'd like to implement a retry task that takes the previous failing tasks action and repeat it.

This is what I have so far. However it just repeats the fact that the task is in fault rather than actually firing the action of the task again.

```
public static async Task<T> Retry<T>(this Task<T> task, int retryCount, int delay, TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = null)
{
    if (tcs == null)
    {
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    }

    await task.ContinueWith(async _original =>
    {
        if (_original.IsFaulted)
        {
            if (retryCount == 0)
            {
                tcs.SetException(_original.Exception.InnerExceptions);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unhandled exception. Retrying...");

                await Task.Delay(delay).ContinueWith(async t =>
                {
                    await Retry(task, retryCount - 1, delay, tcs);
                });
            }
        }
        else
            tcs.SetResult(_original.Result);
    });
    return await tcs.Task;
}
```

I tried to get the action with a little reflection. However it seems that once the task is completed the action is set to null.

```
var action = task
    .GetType()
    .GetField("m_action", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetValue(task) as Action;
```

Ideally I would like my implementation to look like this:

```
try
{
    await MakeFailure().Retry(5, 1000);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I had an exception");
}
```

This may not be possible but I'd like to make sure before refactoring the code to a `Retry(Func<T> task)`

Comment: Would you be against not making this a extension method and changing the method signature to `static async Task<T> Retry<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskFactory, int retryCount, ...`?

Comment: Not completely against it.  But it changes the flow of the code to a fault first layout which I don't like ```Retry(async () => await MakeFailure(),5,1000)``` is not as clean as ```await MakeFailure().Retry(5,1000)```

Comment: Don't try to hack TPL to do something it's not meant for. Create an abstraction above it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Not completely against it. But it changes the flow of the code to a fault first layout which I don't like

Consider your types. `Task` represents an asynchronous operation. In the asynchronous world, `Task` represents an asynchronous operation *that has already started*. `Task` is not something you can "retry".

On the other hand, `Func<Task>` represents an asynchronous operation that can be started. Or restarted. That's what you need to work with.

Once you are using the appropriate type, the code is straightforward:

```
public static async Task<T> Retry<T>(Func<Task<T>> action, int retryCount, int delay)
{
  while (retryCount > 0)
  {
    try
    {
      return await action().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      await Task.Delay(delay).ConfigureAwait(false);
      --retryCount;
    }
  }
  return await action().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Like the other answerer, I recommend you use a library that was actually designed for this. The [Transient Fault Handling Application Block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934(v=pandp.50).aspx) and [Polly](https://github.com/michael-wolfenden/Polly) are two good examples.

Comment: While using the TPL I agree that this is the best answer. I was hoping that a task maintained some details about the action it was / is processing but it appears not.

Comment: @JonathanSheely: In modern (`async`/`await`) code, most tasks do not even *have* actions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really great library out there that you could leverage without writing your own code. It is called the Transient Fault Application Block. But I would start by evaluating a single library in the block called [TransientFaultHandling.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TransientFaultHandling.Core/).

It's used in a way very similar to your code above. Here's a quick example:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        internal class MyTransientErrorDetectionStrategy : ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy
        {
            public bool IsTransient(Exception ex)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int retryCount = 5;
            const int retryIntervalInSeconds = 1;

            // define the strategy for retrying
            var retryStrategy = new FixedInterval(
                retryCount,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryIntervalInSeconds));

            // define the policy 
            var retryPolicy =
                new RetryPolicy<MyTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);

            retryPolicy.Retrying += retryPolicy_Retrying;

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                // try this a few times just to illustrate

                try
                {
                    retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(SomeMethodThatCanSometimesFail);

                    // (the retry policy has async support as well)
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // if it got to this point, your retries were exhausted
                    // the original exception is rethrown
                    throw;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Exit");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void SomeMethodThatCanSometimesFail()
        {
            var random = new Random().Next(1, 4);

            if (random == 2)
            {
                const string msg = "randomFailure";

                Console.WriteLine(msg);

                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
        }

        private static void retryPolicy_Retrying(object sender, RetryingEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("retrying");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While the concept is sound. I find the verbose nature of the API very chatty for this framework. Good a good answer none the less

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you have is that once you have a `Task<T>` in flight it can't be undone or retried. You must start with a `Func<Task<T>>` to be able to retry.

Now you can muck about directly with TPL, but I'd recommend using Microsoft's Reactive Framework to build the functionality you need. It's much much more powerful than TPL.

Given a `Func<Task<T>>` this is what you need:

```
Func<Task<T>> taskFactory = ...
int retryCount = 5;
Task<T> retryingTask = Observable.FromAsync(taskFactory).Retry(retryCount).ToTask();
```

I tested this with this code:

```
var i = 0;

Func<Task<int>> taskFactory = () => Task.Run(() =>
{
    if (i++ == 0)
        throw new Exception("Foo");
    return i;
});

int retryCount = 5;
Task<int> retryingTask = Observable.FromAsync(taskFactory).Retry(retryCount).ToTask();

Console.WriteLine(retryingTask.Result);
```

The Reactive Framework will let you do so much more - it's a very powerful library - but it does make this task very simple. You can NuGet "Rx-Main" to get the bits.

Comment: I have switched to using Rx in many of my other projects. This is exactly why I was wondering if there was a way to do a short hand implementation in the TPL only for just a retry routine.

Comment: @JonathanSheely - Fair enough. I like Rx far more than TPL.